Squid Proxy connection through GCP Private Service Connect with Proxy enabled (for getting client IPs making the request) error
We are trying to access the Squid Proxy Hosted in VM in GCP project exposed through PSC Published service from another project. We are not able to do it , getting the error:  Received HTTP code 400 from proxy after CONNECT .
In Squid access logs getting the error : Received HTTP code 400 from proxy after CONNECT .
Source IP is PSC Published service IP range and not the Client IP range.
